# SequelizeJs Associations in NodeJs for MsSql

Tags: sql-server, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have pre existing tables in SQL Server and I wanna use these tables in NodeJs project.

First table is the Report table and it has {ReportId, ReportName} columns.

Second table is the Favourites table and it has {FavouriteId, ReportId, UserName} columns.

You can find model defines below. I would like to assign foreign keys and make dependency. At the end I want to select reports with favourite flag for a specific user.

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var Favourite = sequelize.define("IUI_Favourites", {
            favourite_id: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                primaryKey: true,
                field: 'iui_favourite_id' 
            },
            report_id: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                field: 'iui_report_id' 
            },
            username: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                field: 'iui_username'
            }
        },
        {
            timestamps: false,
            freezeTableName: true
        });
    return Favourite;
};


module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    var Report = sequelize.define("IUI_Reports", {
        report_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            field: 'iui_report_id' 
        },
        report_name: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            field: 'iui_report_name' 
        }
    },
    {
         timestamps: false,
         freezeTableName: true
    });
    return Report;
};
```

Can you help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `Favourite` model you need to create property `classMethods` with `associate` function.

```
    // in Favourite model
    classMethods: {
        associate: function(models){
            this.belongsTo(models.Report, { foreignKey: 'iui_report_id' });
        }
    },
    timestamps: false,
    freezeTableName: true
});
```

This defines that model `Favourite` can have `Report` assigned via `iui_report_id` foreign key field in the database.

Then, in the `Report` model you would have to define 1:M relation:

```
    // in Report model
    classMethods: {
        associate: function(models){
            this.hasMany(models.Favourite, { foreignKey: 'iui_report_id' });
        }
    },
    timestamps: false,
    freezeTableName: true
});
```

In order to return reports that are favourited by specified user, you would have to call a `findAll()` method on `Report` with specified conditions:

```
Report.findAll({
     include: [
         {
             model: Favourite,
             where: {
                 username: 'admin'
             }
         }
     ]
}).then((reports) => {
    // here you get reports that are favourited by user with username 'admin'
});
```

This would generate a SQL query which would return both `Report` and `Favourite` objects using `JOIN` condition on `reports.id = favourite.report_id` and `favourite.username = 'admin'`. I hope that this is what you are looking for.

**EDIT**

According to the comments, you want to set favourite flag to `true` if specified report was favourited by any user. In order to do that, you would have to add this flag field to the `Report` model, something like `is_favourited`. It can be a field stored in database or it can be a [virtual](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/datatypes/#virtual) sequelize field with it's own `getter` (virtual fields are not stored in the database).

In case of virtual field it could look like that:

```js
var Report = sequelize.define('report', {
    ...
    is_favourited: {
        type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL(DataTypes.BOOLEAN),
        get: function() {
            return sequelize.models.Favourite.count({
                where: { iui_report_id: this.get('report_id') }
            }).then((countResult) => {
                return countResult > 0;
            });
        }
    }
}, {
   // additional model options e.g. classMethods etc.
});
```

This virtual attribute returns `true` if there is any `Favourite` object with specified `iui_report_id` value. However, it is asynchronous so you need to call it with `.then()` like `report.get('is_favourited').then((result) => { console.log(result); });`

On the other hand, if you would like to store that flag in database, you would have to manually set the `is_favourited` field value to true when creating new `Favourite` model instance. In order to do that you can use the [`afterCreate`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/hooks/) hook on the `Favourite` model.

```js
// in Favourite model
timestamps: false,
freezeTableName: true,
hooks: {
    afterCreate: function(instance, options) {
        return sequelize.models.Report.findById(instance.get('iui_report_id').then((report) => {
             if ( company && !company.get('is_favourited') ) {
                 return company.set('is_favourited', true).save().then(() => { return; });
             }
    }
}

// in Report model
var Report = sequelize.define('report', {
    ...
    is_favourited: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: false
    }
}, {
   // other model options...
});
```

**EDIT 2**

According to your last comment you want to create a query like this

```
SELECT Reps.rep_id, Reps.rep_name, CASE WHEN Favs.rep_id IS NULL THEN FALSE ELSE TRUE END is_favourited
FROM Reps
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT rep_id FROM Favs WHERE user = 'alex') Favs ON Reps.rep_id = Favs.rep_id
```

This query would always return `is_favourited = TRUE`, because your `ON` condition in the `JOIN` clause is `Reps.rep_id = Favs.rep_id`, so even if `Favs.rep_id` is `NULL`, then the `ON` condition would not pass (because `Reps.rep_id` is a primary key and cannot be `NULL`).

However, if you really want to perform such a query, it would look like this

```
Report.findAll({
    include: [
        {
            model: Favourite,
            where: { username: 'alex' }, // or any other passed value
            attributes: []
        }
    ],
    attributes: ['report_id', 'report_name', sequelize.literal('CASE WHEN "IUI_Favourites"."report_id" IS NULL THEN FALSE ELSE TRUE END is_favourited')],
    raw: true // because your Report model does not have is_favourited field
}).then((rows) => {
    // result
});
```

Comment: Great answer thank you. Last thing, I want to get all reports with a favourite flag. It means if one report is favourited by admin user, flag should be true otherwise false. How can it be possible? And when I select tables, favourite table comes plural. How can I get that singular?

Comment: I do not fully understand the part with favourite flag. You mean that if specific report was favourited by ANY user, it should have favourite flag set to true? If it comes to the favourite table, it comes in plural due to the fact that this is 1:M relation so `Report` object comes with many `Favourite` objects.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, favourite flag is the first question. Plural part is the second question. Favourite flag is the important part. And yes you are right, if a report was favourited by any user, it should have favourite flag set to true otherwise false.  If you help I will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I updated the answer to include the favourite flag and how to set it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But it does not satisfy my neccesity. Actually I would like to call a query like below:

Select Reps.rep_id, Reps.rep_name, case when Favs.rep_id is null then false else true end is_favourited From Reps left outer join (select rep_id from Favs where user='alex') Favs on Reps.rep_id=Favs.rep_id 

As we can see in the query, I want to pass user name as param and get all the reports with a conditional field is_favourited.

Thanks